# How to execute bash script with PHP?

Tags: php, linux, bash

I have a bash script which I want to take a parameter, it all works fine normally so that is not the issue.

What is I want is an HTML (or PHP if need be) which will take text entered into a text field and execute a bash script with it as a parameter.

I had my HTML working last night with some embedded PHP (I didn't attempt to pass argument at this stage):

```
<?php
    exec("/scriptname.sh");
?>
```

This however would simply not execute the script (yes it is located at /). I had a simple "echo test > testfile" command which obviously did not run.

What is the easiest way to do what I need, and an example would also be great.

Thanks a lot for taking the time to read this.

Comment: I'm sure this question is asked earlier...

Comment: Try using shell_exec rather than exec

Comment: Apache / PHP / mod_fcgi may not have the relevant permissions to run a script created by root (if you've ssh'd in and created the script with vi or nano). Try moving the script to a directory that your PHP user has permission on. Also try `chown`ing  your bash script to change the owner to the same user or group as your FTP or Apache user, environment depending.

Comment: "Here's my code, it doesn't work" kind of questions are already bad enough. But you aren't even asking for help with your code, you apparently just what someone to look up `exec()` in the PHP manual and paste the information here for you.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, I have looked up exec myself, and also tried shell_exec. If you look more closely at my question I am asking for the best way to execute a bash script with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look on shell_exec

```
$output = shell_exec('/scriptname.sh p1 p2 p3');
```

Documentation

http://www.php.net/shell_exec

Comment: Thanks. I did try shell_exec but without assigning it to $output. Is this done so it executes upon completion?

Comment: running shell_exec without getting the output works as well

Comment: I'm not a web dev at all, so in true noob fashion I was ignorant to the fact you need an apache server to run PHP. Going to use JS to do this instead.